# Use vue-i18n inside script

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a simple project [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/i18n-7luth?fontsize=14)

I use [/vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n)

**Hello World** template:

```
<h1>{{msg}}</h1>
```

And **script**:

```
data() {
    return {
      msg: `{{ $t("welcomeMsg") }}`
    }
  }
```

**Plugins/i18n.js :**

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    welcomeMsg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
  },
  es: {
    welcomeMsg: "Bienvenido a tu aplicación Vue.js",
  }
};
```

**Question:** How I can Use vue-i18n from script like `msg:`{{ $t("welcomeMsg") }}?

**P.S:** `this.$t("welcomeMsg")` this is work but noy translate!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For an ES6 template string, you need to use `${ }` syntax instead of `{{ }}`:

```js
msg: `${this.$t("welcomeMsg")}`
```

But using a template string is unnecessary here (unless you want to add additional text before or after the message); just do this:

```js
msg: this.$t("welcomeMsg")
```

And finally, if you're not planning on modifying `msg`, then it should be a computed property:

```js
computed: {
  msg() {
    return this.$t("welcomeMsg")
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "it should be a computed property" - I was putting them in my data section and in some cases that did not work

Comment: I tried using this, but get error "TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined". Any idea why "this" is "undefined"?

Comment: It works fine to get it once, but when I change the language the word is not translated until I hard reload the page.

Comment: @HyungTaeCarapetoFigur It will auto-update if you used a computed property, but as a data property it will not.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thank you. But I've solved my problem by writing the necessary logic inside the template.

Comment: Hi, you can find better solutions here -> https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149

Comment: how to use it in vue 3?

Comment: In Vue 3 import your script: `import i18n from '@/i18n'`  and use `i18n.global.t('message')` inside script tag.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to user115014's comment, this is how you use it in Vue3 with the composition api.

```
import {useI18n} from "vue-i18n";
        
const i18n = useI18n();
const translatedMessage = i18n.t("welcomeMsg");
```

Comment: With Nuxt3 auto-import, you can omit the `import` line as it will happen automatically. And as @saswanb said, consider making it a computed property if the language switcher affects layout type of content.